# While loop with user input with minor parameters using && / ||

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I'm trying to enter a condition where the user gets caught in a while loop until they enter a decimal between `.00` and `.025`, no higher or lower.

```
System.out.println("Enter the interest rate you would like, preferablly between .00 and .25");
while ((interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble()) < 0.00 || ((interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble()) < 0.25))
{
    System.out.println("Just a number between .00 and .25, no more, no less!");
}
System.out.println("Testing for break");
```

I'm unable to get the accursed thing to run both ways properly, but always run into a blank.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `keyboard.nextDouble()` twice inside the condition (although only the first will be evaluated if the (first!) input is in fact negative).  Probably, don't call it at all inside the condition:

```
while(true) {
  interestRate=keyboard.nextDouble();
  if(interestRate>=0 && interestRate<=0.25) break;
  System.out.println("...");
}
```

(The conditional for 0.25 was also backwards in your version.)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `nextDouble()` twice, and your second condition is reversed. Try this:

```
while ((interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble()) < 0.00 || interestRate > 0.25)
```